# Order by "In clause"

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, ase

I have a query wherein I use "In" clause in it.
Now I wish to have the result set in same order as my In clause.
For example -

```
select Id,Name from mytable where id in (3,6,7,1)
```

Result Set :

```
|Id | Name |
------------
| 3 |  ABS |
| 6 |  NVK |
| 7 |  USD |
| 1 |  KSK |
```

I do not want to use any temp table.
Is it possible to achieve the goal in one query?

Comment: Put 3,6,7,1 in a table, INNER JOIN to it, ORDER BY it

Comment: Is this interview questions? Why would you want to do it at all? And why using just 1 query? If it's a genuine requirement, you may have thousands of rows instead of just 4.

Comment: @Meet It is not interview question but yes a colleague from work tricked me with this, and he does take interviews for our team :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In T-SQL, you can do this using a big `case`:

```
select Id, Name
from mytable
where id in (3, 6, 7, 1)
order by (case id when 3 then 1 when 6 then 2 when 7 then 3 else 4 end);
```

Or with `charindex()`:

```
order by charindex(',' + cast(id as varchar(255)) + ',',
                   ',3,6,7,1,')
```

Comment: i think he wants this in the sybase only, not in MSSQL. So no charindex will work

Comment: @AnkitBajpai . . . Sybase supports `charindex()`.

Comment: Yes, Sybase ASE 15 does support charindex() - I was trying with charindex at the start but may be was thinking incorrectly.
But I got my result with both of Gordon's logic. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can use CTE as well

```
with filterID as 
(
  3 ID, 1 as sequence
  union 
  6, 2
  union 
  7, 3
  union 
  1, 4
)

select mytable.* from mytable 
inner join filterID on filterID.ID = mytable.ID
order by filterID.sequence ;
```